# How to linkify the URL in a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Html, Jquery and Javascript. I am using `linkify` javascript library and is working fine. But if there is no space before the URL then it does not work. How to solve this? I have below URL along with text.

```
Please click the linkhttp://www.asdfgh.com
```

Please see there is no space before the URL. How to linkify the URL here?Can it be done using Javascript?

Comment: Use JavaScript RegExp for that.

Comment: Don't you think it would be more beneficial to simply fix your markup? Adding spaces where appropriate?

Comment: I should not add spaces.

Comment: @user755806 Even if it means your content not being very readable?

Comment: but I am not allowed to add spaces....

Comment: To me `linkhttp://www.asdfgh.com` is a typo

Answer (score 0):

don't Know linkify. Maybe there is an option for setting individual patterns.
Otherways you could search the text for this string and replace it, before linkify do its work. But its dirty.

```
yourtext=yourtext.replace("linkhttp://","link http://");
```

Comment: My text is dynamic.I cannot hardcode it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But somewhere the text will set to content. There you have to change it.